# Chrome push notifications log

Tags: python, node.js, google-chrome, push-notification, storage

How can read chrome push notifications log (
macos - ~/Library/ApplicationSupport/Google/Chrome/Default/Platform Notifications/000003.log,
linux - /home/user/.config/google-chrome/Profile 1/Platform Notifications/000003.log). I need get by script (js, python).
What kind of storage is used for log?

Comment: Check this: https://superuser.com/questions/1035042/is-there-any-way-to-view-chrome-browser-notifications-history

Comment: Also have look at the Chromium src: https://chromium.googlesource.com/experimental/chromium/src/+/refs/wip/bajones/webvr/content/browser/notifications/platform_notification_context_impl.cc